# GRUB won't boot after Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: boot, grub2, apt

After I updated my system with `apt-get upgrade`, I rebooted and landed at the `grub>` promt.

I wasn't able to set any root and booted always to kernel panic. I then started a live CD and used https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair. After I used this tool I now get:

```
error: out of disk    
error: could't read file.
press any key to continue...
```

Here is what `boot-repair` produced: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1691134/

Can somebody guide me to the right setup for my problem or how I reset the grub settings to the proper ones?

Comment: Yes this would be the best i guess. I did not know this one

Comment: I solved it by creating a boot partition with gparted at the very beginning off the raid hdd (first 1 GB). I installed grub there and everything was ok then.

Answer (score 2):

The OP solved the problem and posted the solution in a comment:

> I solved it by creating a boot partition with gparted at the very
>   beginning off the raid hdd (first 1 GB). I installed grub there and
>   everything was ok then.

– [Andreas](https://askubuntu.com/users/135481/andreas) [Mar 5 at 11:22](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259240/grub-wont-boot-after-ubuntu-upgrade#comment330632_259240)

Answer (score 0):

I would boot to the USB installer , launch a terminal and run sudo grub-install ( followed by your hdd mount point ) then sudo grub-update